# Progress Dialog spins forever on Activity Resume

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog, android-lifecycle, android-progressbar

I am calling WebServices with Handler and showing ProgressBar with the help of

---

```
// Create Progress dialogs
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case mDialogProgress:
            dataLoadProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dataLoadProgress.setMessage("Loading...");
            dataLoadProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
            dataLoadProgress.setCancelable(false);
            dataLoadProgress
                    .setProgressStyle(android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmallTitle);
            return dataLoadProgress;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
```

---

I am already calling the below method onStop to stop if its showing.

```
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            if (dataLoadProgress != null && dataLoadProgress.isShowing())
                stopThread();
            super.onStop();
        }

        private synchronized void stopThread() {
        try {
            if (getServerData != null) {
                if (dataLoadProgress != null && dataLoadProgress.isShowing())
                    dismissDialog(mDialogProgress);
                getServerData = null;
                // // mHandler = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            CommonFunctions.DoCatchOperation(e);
        }
        }
```

Now when my Apps goto background mode and resume, it shows progressdialog and it spins forever and I can't stop it using back button as its **setCancelable(false);**

I have tried with calling my **stopThread()** in **onResume()** that if the progress is showing then it'll stop, but Im calling webservice in onCreate and it starts to show ProgressDialog and at next instance after onCreate onResume is calling and my ProgressDialog is dismissed.

**So I want to stop this spins forever in background.**

Comment: Oh my god. You and implemented this Threading mechanism. Why? You can try AsyncTask instead. And you are displaying Dialog this way?

Comment: @PareshMayani I have 32 Activities now and I am working on the implemented code.. so just trying to fix with the existing code first if possible..

Comment: 32 Activities then what? Can't you define Super AsyncTask class and extends it in all these 32 activities.? You just has to write dialog show in the super base task.

Comment: @PareshMayani okay.. that is fine.. but do you have any Idea why the Dialog is resumed ? as its already dismissed before onPause/onStop and not even showing it again.

Answer (score 2):

I added just one line of condition here.
**if(dataLoadProgress == null)**  and it worked for me.

```
// Create Progress dialogs
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case mDialogProgress:
        if(dataLoadProgress == null)
            dataLoadProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dataLoadProgress.setMessage("Loading...");
        dataLoadProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
        dataLoadProgress.setCancelable(false);
        dataLoadProgress
                .setProgressStyle(android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmallTitle);
        return dataLoadProgress;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```